# Display file preview in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a dialog box which contains a browse button.
I have a requirement where I need to browse through a location in my local system and then whatever file the user selects(it may be pdf,doc,excel etc) he/she should be able to preview it in the dialog box itself.
Can anyone help me out with this.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the dialog box custom or are you on about something like a JDialog?

Comment: there is JFileChooser ???

Answer (score 1):

In `JFileChooser` you can use `setAccessory`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29

Though you'll have to write the preview component yourself. And when it comes to docs and excels it won't be a breeze.